# Are autowired repositories thread safe in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, thread-safety

If I have a standard CrudRepository and a Controller like below, is this thread safe? I know that this class is treated as a singleton, but wasn't sure if Spring handles repositories in a special way that allows for no handling on my side.

```java
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private TestRepository testRepository;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/test")
    public void addTest() {
        TestObj o = new TestObj();
        testRepository.save(o);
    }
}
```

```java
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<TestObj, Integer> {

}
```

Comment: The _repository_ has no threading concerns, but you will usually want `@Transactional` to ensure transaction semantics on your database (presuming they are available).

Comment: it seems you don't really understand what "thread safety" is. an interface has no _instance_ mutable fields, so it's methods can't alter those fields.

Answer (score 0):

The standard CrudRepository is not threadSafe.But i think that you ask about how the data concurrent access are handling?
first you should to know that there are several phenomes that may occur when using transaction  simultaneously and can affect the integrity of data such as: lost update, dirty read, unrepeatable read, last commit wins and phantom read.
For managing these phenomes according to your requirement spring offer the possibility to specify the desired isolation level  inside @Transactional annotation.
for more information :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.bootstrap-mode